# In what order should I read build errors from MSVC compiler?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, c++14, cl

I have recently tried to build a library on Windows via CMake that I managed to succesfully build on Linux. Unfortunately, there is quite a long list of errors, despite very similar compiler options between `g++` / `cl`. I am having a hard time to find out where the real problem is, especially since most of these errors does not make sense (they are probably side-effects of another error).

**Is there a project-independent procedure that I can follow to find the root cause? Is there any, however complicated, order of errors in `cl` output?**

Below, for the reference, list of errors I'm fighting against (removed full paths for readability). I have checked manually all the errors (checked types, class members etc. ). The only difference between compiler flags is standard (`g++` is `c++98`, `cl` is `c++14`, but that should not matter in this direction, right? )

Cheers!

```
affixsplit.cpp
Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(48,39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(48,27): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(72,42): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(72,42): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(79,42): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(79,42): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(80,37): error C2535: 'Toki::Token *Toki::Token::clone_changed(const int) const': member function already defined or declared
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(72): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token::clone_changed'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(123,21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(123,21): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(123,36): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(128,35): error C2327: 'Toki::Token::UnicodeString': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(128,35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(128,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(167,16): error C2327: 'Toki::Token::UnicodeString': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(167,21): error C3646: 'orth_': unknown override specifier
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(167,21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(129,3): error C2065: 'orth_': undeclared identifier
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(129,11): error C2065: 'new_orth': undeclared identifier
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(55,35): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(56,26): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(58,11): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(57,17): error C2660: 'Toki::Token::clone_changed': function does not take 2 arguments
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(72,9): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token::clone_changed'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(63,30): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(65,26): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(70,1): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(74,4): error C2065: 'UnicodeString': undeclared identifier
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(74,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'body_orth'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(74,18): error C2065: 'body_orth': undeclared identifier
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(75,11): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(76,6): error C2065: 'body_orth': undeclared identifier
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(77,35): error C2065: 'body_orth': undeclared identifier
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(82,33): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(84,11): error C2039: 'orth': is not a member of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(39): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token'
toki\cc\libtoki\layers\affixsplit.cpp(83,18): error C2660: 'Toki::Token::clone_changed': function does not take 2 arguments
toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(72,9): note: see declaration of 'Toki::Token::clone_changed'
```

Couple of LOC for the first error

```cpp
class Token
{
public:
    Token(const UnicodeString& orth, const std::string& type, // line 48, col 39 at second const
            PwrNlp::Whitespace::Enum wa_before);


    Token(const char* orth_utf8, const std::string& type,
            PwrNlp::Whitespace::Enum wa_before);

    /**
```

---

**Update with found root cause:** `UnicodeString` is in a different namespace with updated library, and first error pointed to a proper line, just not a proper element.

Comment: What's here:  `toki\cc\libtoki/token.h(48,39)` +- 2 lines please ?  Feels like a function return type specified using a macro that is not defined.

Comment: I would start by addressing the `Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results` message. It appears that there is a header file that has compiler-dependent blocks and that this doesn't 'recognize' your MSVC.

Comment: @AdrianMole that's probably old boost (1.65.1) and toolset is MSCV 2019. I am not sure I can update it to 1.7x.x since it's an old library but I will give it a try. Thank you :)

Comment: @RichardCritten I updated my question with code :)

Comment: @AdrianMole updated with 1.72.0, warning is gone, errors are there

Comment: Please add mark where is line `48` and much more context would be helpful.

Comment: @MarekR all includes are there :) plus I compiled it on Linux so it would be weird if I failed only now

Comment: [Based on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2143?view=vs-2019) I'm suspecting you have some template there. More code context is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to "In what order should I read build errors from MSVC compiler?":

**Always start with the first reported error.**

Only consider later errors if you strongly believe the earlier errors cannot be their cause.

For example, @AdrianMole immediately honed in on your first error: "For example I would start by addressing the Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results message."

BTW: have you seen https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for the answer, I updated my question with solution to my particular problem but in the end I was asking about a general rule, so thanks again :)

Comment: @Proko, Glad you got both kinds of help ;-)